# Are word lists forbidden in the rules?

Tags: discussion, support

I replied to a poster who asked me to supply a list of words in a particular category, that this was not allowed in the rules. [See](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/271507/which-verbs-call-for-to-and-which-dont?noredirect=1#comment506414_271507)

When I tried to search for the rule, I couldn't find it (or indeed any list of rules for answers). Am I wrong? I'm sure I've seen other commenters state that this was the case.

Comment: Yes, ask for  lists of words is  not on topic as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this meta meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic) covers the issue of lists in general. That is, no, lists are not allowed because each answer is equally valid.

We used to allow list questions on EL&U so long as they were Community Wiki ([see this meta question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/why-are-list-questions-supposed-to-be-community-wikis-usually-those-questions-d)). I think they've been outlawed due to their subjective nature.

The example you've linked to does ask for a list, but I think it can be answered without one. I don't think providing the list would be helpful (so very very long) or even achievable, as the list would inevitably change as the language evolves, and may be different depending on dialect.